# Proving $(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ when there exists $J$ so that $J^2 = -I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I'm having trouble proving this biconditional statement:

> Prove that there exist $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ if and only if there exists $J \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $J^2 = -I_n$.

Here, $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. So far, none of my ideas have panned out and I don't feel like I have enough information to solve this problem. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: it might be true that $J$ exists for even $n$ only.

Comment: @WW1 What's this 'might'? we can do $\det$ on both sides of $J^2=-I_n$ to get even $n$ right?

Comment: FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\Longrightarrow)$

Since
$(A+B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})= I + AB^{-1}+BA^{-1} + I=(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}=I$

$AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}=AB^{-1}+(AB^{-1})^{-1}=-I$ and $ (AB^{-1})^2+I=-AB^{-1}$

and if we let $X=AB^{-1}$, then we have $X^2+X+I=O$.

We can do a change of variables $X=Y+C$

$(Y+C)^2+(Y+C)+I=Y^2 +(2C+I)Y+C^2+C+I$

and by letting $C=-\frac{1}{2}I$, then we get $Y^2+0Y+\frac{3}{4}I=Y^2+\frac{3}{4}I=O$

now $\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}Y\right)^2+I=Z^2+I=0$ and $Z=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(X+\frac{1}{2}I\right)$ satisfies the properties of $J$.

---

$(\Longleftarrow)$

Given $J$ s.t. $J^2=-I$, then let $Z=-\frac{1}{2}I+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J$

then $\left(-\frac{1}{2}I+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}I-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J\right)= \frac{1}{4}I^2-\frac{3}{4}J^2= \frac{1}{4}I+\frac{3}{4}I=I$ and $Z$ is invertible.

$Z$ also satisfies $Z^2 + Z +I =O$

$\left(-\frac{1}{2}I+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J\right)^2 + \left(-\frac{1}{2}I+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J\right)+ I=\frac{1}{4}I^2-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J+\frac{3}{4}J^2-\frac{1}{2}I+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J+I$

$=\frac{1}{4}I-\frac{3}{4}I-\frac{1}{2}I+I=O$

Given an invertible matrix $B$, let $ZB=A$, and then $Z=AB^{-1}$ where $A$ is invertible because $Z$ and $B$ are inverible.

$(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=(A+B)^{-1}$ because $Z+Z^{-1}=AB^{-1}+BA^{-1} = -\frac{1}{2}I + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J -\frac{1}{2}I -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}J =-I$

thus $I+AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}+I=(A+B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=I$.

Answer (score 7):

First, write $B = XA.$ (this is always possible, since $B$ is invertible). Then, you get

$$(A+XA)^{-1} = A^{-1} + A^{-1}X^{-1}.$$ Factoring out the $A^{-1}$ from both sides, we get

$$(I+X)^{-1}= (I + X^{-1}).$$  Multiply this through by $I+X$ to get:

$$I = (I+X^{-1})(I+X),$$ whence it follows that $$X = (I+X)^2,$$ so the minimal polynomial of $X$ is $$X^2+X+I=0,$$ or $$\left(X+\frac12I\right)^2 = -\frac{3}{4} I,$$ so

$$\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}(X+\frac12I)\right)^2 = -I.$$

Every step in the above is an equivalence, so proves both directions.